# Bootstrap 4 Separators in navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to place separators in a `navbar` between the `nav-items`, but I have no idea how to set padding on separators in equal range between the `nav-item`.

[image]

My second problem is that, the separators have appeared in the `toggle-navbar` (when the `navbar` is collapsed) and I've tried to remove them, but unsuccessfully.

[image]

If someone knows a better way to create separators, I would be thankful.

Here is my code:

```css
.navbar-nav > li > a::after {
    content: "|";
    padding: 0 5px
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
  <!--
  1) collapse - class dedicate to a given alement
  2) navbar-collapse:  show elements to bootstrap which belong to navbar, then use function - collapse
  -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">O nas</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Cennik</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Usługi</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Rejestracja</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Porady</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a picture of what you try to achieve ? I don't really understand what you want to do

Comment: I've just added links to pictures in my post. Separators,  I mean these vertical lines

Answer (score 6):

Maybe a `border-right` CSS style on your `nav-items` will do the work, and you can disable they on a specific `break-point` (`MD` is the chosen breakpoint on the next example).

```css
.border-md-right {
  border-right: 1px solid silver;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

  .border-md-right {
    border-right: none;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active border-md-right">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">O nas</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active border-md-right">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Cennik</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active border-md-right">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Usługi</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active border-md-right">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Rejestracja</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Porady</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking for something like this. This solved my problem :)

Comment: @Mr.Daniel please consider to up-vote and check the answer as correct if this helps you, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

@Shidersz solution should work. Another solution if you don't want to add an extra class in every `li`. Also may be a bit more difficult if you have a dynamic menu and you have to add this class to every element except the last one!

```css
.navbar-nav .nav-item:not(:last-child) {
   border-right: 1px solid silver;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav .nav-item:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">O nas</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Cennik</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Usługi</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Rejestracja</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Porady</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me using Bootstrap 4

```
.navbar-nav > li > a::after {
    content:'|';
    padding-left:10px;
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        content: none;
        padding-left:0;
    }
}
 .navbar-nav > li:last-child > a::after {
         content:none;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution using `last-child`.. the formatting was a bit off though & the first line wasn't showing so I edited to move the backticks to a separate line

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap 5 this works

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And the CSS

```
.navbar-nav > li > a::after {
    content: '|';
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.navbar-nav > li:last-child > a::after {
    content: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure bootstrap 5 with no additional css:

```
<li class="nav-item"><hr class="d-lg-none" /><span class="nav-link d-none d-lg-block mx-2">|</span></li>
```